# uses of frameworks

Tags: frameworks

Personally i dont like to use Frameworks i think it will deprieve you from basics of language..what you people think about this...

Comment: If you have the time to reinvent the wheel every time, go ahead. But if you'd use a framework you'd probably have the time to phrase this question a little nicer.

Comment: If you are using a .net based application and you don't like the framework then how much time will you take to make an application?

Comment: This should be community wiki, but shouldn't be down voted.

Comment: Given that the responses have been (so far) fairly consistent, I'd say that this isn't all that subjective. As for argumentative, the only person doing that is the OP by suggesting an absurd stance, everyone else is pretty much in agreement that not using frameworks is a bad idea and counterproductive.

Answer (score 12):

I don't have the time to write everything I need myself. Therefore I use frameworks.

Answer (score 4):

I think using a framework allows you to focus on solving the real business problems of your customers and not waste your time on writing the same generic code time and time again. Furthermore a good framework is extensively tested and used by a large group of people, which ensures the quality is generally higher than a one of solution.

Answer (score 2):

Frameworks are just a result of an extended period of time using a specific language, and the features embedded within them just make things which are usually tedious, trivial - a great example of that would be the Javascript library jQuery, where even something as simple as assigning a function on dom ready has been abstracted such so that it's supported cross-browser and is very easy to type, eg

```
$(function() {
// code
});
```

As opposed to writing 50-100+ lines of DOM Scripting to account for inconsistencies of the DOM API across Webkit, Gecko, Presto, Trident, et cetera.

What particular frameworks have you tried and not liked?

Answer (score 2):

The wheel has already been invented - why go back?

Answer (score 2):

Hmmmm you must have a lot of time on your hands...

Personally I really like using the .NET framework in various forms depending on the context of software (ASP.NET, Compact Framework, Silverlight, WF, etc. etc.) I'd really hate having to rewrite data management tools and configuration tools, just to mention some basic often used functionality.

Another thing is: I would have to work a lot more to figure out your code if I was working with you in a team, when you don't use frameworks/standards. That would not win a star on my sky...

Answer (score 1):

I **do** have time to reinvent the wheel everytime, but if I get to choose between implementing my own Data Structures, Sort Algorithms, File I/O Operations and UI Library and actually writing an Application that provides value to the user, I usually choose the second option.

That is, unless the implementation of something in the Framework does not suit my needs **and** I can't design my application around the framework. Which happens rarely.

By the way, strictly speaking, you are almost always using a Framework. If you code in C or C++, very often you use something like `#include <stdio.h>` which means you ARE already using a Framework: The C Standard Library. In .net, the BCL is a Framework. ANd I'm sure that Java, Python and Ruby also have a standard Framework built on top of the language.

Answer (score 0):

For learning a new language or a new library/package (say OpenID, MySQL), yes, it's good to stay away from frameworks. But once you start developing projects, libraries are good to have. It's good to have a grasp of how things work under the hood, but it doesn't mean you have to do it from ground up all the time. And other frameworks have been 'eye-balled' by many people and I doubt I can write a vector better than the one provided in STL.